# How to programmatically remove a user from an organic group

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I have found many examples about how to add a user to an organic group but I can't find any info on how to remove a user from an organic group programmatically. Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of me thinks that `og_membership_delete` would be a good option, you can pass the entity ID in as a parameter (and by "can", I really mean "need to"). Also, `og_ungroup` seems useful as well.

You can find more functions that OG defines at: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/7

Here's an example of `og_ungroup`:

```
og_ungroup('node', $gid, 'user', $uid);
```